# CodeLearn Twitter Tutorial nullpointer error on TweetAdapter.java

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm currently doing the Codelearn Twitter tutorial but I'm getting a null pointer in my code below - can someone please help me?

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Tweet> tweetsList;

 public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets) {
     super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
     tweetsList = (ArrayList<Tweet>) tweets;
     inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    Tweet t = tweetsList.get(position);

    ***TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);***
    TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);

    title.setText(t.getTitle());
    body.setText(t.getBody());

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
    }
```

}

Comment: Where are you getting the `NullPointerException`? Where the stars are?

Comment: On the Line TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);

Comment: Just to be sure, can you also put your XML file so that it can be confirmed there is a field with id tweetTitle. Also, any link to the tutorial where instruction can be checked ?

Comment: Below answer fixed it - thanks for you replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertView` can be null. There is no guarantee that it will be non null. If there is no old view to reuse it will be null

Change

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

Tweet t = tweetsList.get(position);

***TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);***
TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);

title.setText(t.getTitle());
body.setText(t.getBody());

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
}
```

to

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  if(convertView==null)
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);

  Tweet t = tweetsList.get(position);

  ***TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);***
  TextView body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);

  title.setText(t.getTitle());
  body.setText(t.getBody());

  return convertView;
}
```

You have to check whether `convertView` is `non null` or not and if it is `null` you need to inflate your layout in it.

You should also take a look at [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Comment: Thanks Apoorv - I'll give that a whirl