# Null Pointer Exception ListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the following code. Any idea why?

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet>{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<Tweet> values;

    public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, List<Tweet> tweets){
        super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, tweets);
        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();

        context = this.getContext();
        values = tweets;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_tweet, parent, false);
//The exception is here
        TextView headerView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        TextView bodyView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);
        headerView.setText(values.get(position).getTitle());
        bodyView.setText(values.get(position).getBody());
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Tom

If it helps there is a similar question here: [CodeLearn Twitter Tutorial nullpointer error on TweetAdapter.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079699/codelearn-twitter-tutorial-nullpointer-error-on-tweetadapter-java) (however I couldn't get this fix to work)

Comment: at which line do you get the error?

Comment: you never assign tweets to values

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks, but didn't fix the issue

Comment: @MD The logcat gave a NullPointerExeption error at line 42

Comment: @MatthiasG Line 42 (there is a comment in the code)

Comment: `activity.getLayoutInflater()` is enough